# Is there a bug in Play2 testing with FakeRequests and chunked responses (Enumerator)?

Tags: testing, playframework, chunked

I ran into an issue with Play 2.3.7 when testing an Action that returns a chunked response using an enumerator:

```
def text = Action {
    Ok.chunked(Enumerator("abc"))
}
```

Using `curl http://localhost:9000/text` I get the expected result: `abc` but the following test:

```
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {
    "Application" should {
        "stream text" in new WithApplication{
            val request = route(FakeRequest(GET, "/text")).get
            contentAsString(request) mustEqual "abc"
        }
    }
}
```

fails with a comparison error:

```
[info] Application should
[info] x stream text
[error]    '3
[error]    abc
[error]    0
[error]    
[error]    ' is not equal to 'abc' (ApplicationSpec.scala:31)
```

Where do those extra characters come from? I suspect that it might be an issue with FakeRequest and Enumerators? In a more complex case with concatenated Enumerators in the Action there will be characters mixed in between the content generated by the Enumerators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been fixed for the upcoming Play 2.4, but is not available in 2.3.x. The extra characters are introduced from the chunked encoding. They represent chunk lengths in hexadecimal that are at the beginning of each HTTP response body. The old play test helper is just concatenating them together, instead of weeding them out.

I've been using the following code to work around the problem on 2.3.x for now (Thanks to marcuslinke's post from this [github issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2710)):

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import akka.util.Timeout

def contentAsBytes(of: Future[Result])(implicit timeout: Timeout): Array[Byte] = {
    val result = Await.result(of, timeout.duration)
    val eBytes = result.header.headers.get(TRANSFER_ENCODING) match {
        case Some("chunked") => result.body &> Results.dechunk
        case _ => result.body
    }
    Await.result(eBytes |>>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]](), timeout.duration)
}
```

Which I use in tests (specs2) like this:

```
new String(contentAsBytes(result)) must equalTo("expected value")
```

For reference, here is the [pull request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3395) that was merged into master.